# Updating WordPress on local server (max execution time)

Tags: wordpress, local, max, execution

For some time I have been getting a "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" while trying to update different WP installations on my local server.

I know I can fix this by disabling it in the php.ini.. but what I want to do is find the problem and fix it generally. It's a local server after all, so this action should take just few seconds of time.

My local server is running on XAMPP.

The exact message from the WP admin:

> Downloading update from http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.5-new-bundled.zip…
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in E:\Local Server\htdocs\test wp\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 949

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to temporarily increase your max execution time you can use `ini_set()` in your php page

`ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes`

otherwise you'll need to do it in php.ini

`max_execution_time = 30`

Change the value (in seconds) or set to 0 for infinite time and restart Apache for the setting to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as I said above - it's not extending or disabling the "max_execution_time" what I want to do.. I just want to find out the problem. Probably infinite loop somewhere on the core WP scripts? I can't think of another reason at this time.

Comment: so then you are trying to find out what is taking long to execute... the error is pretty obvious its taking a long time for the file to download, although you are on a local server you are downloading an external file which is 5.2 megs, so if you are on a slow connection, its possible that it would take longer than 30 seconds...

Comment: Agree, but that's not my case. I have ~ 10MBps connection, and the WP servers are pretty fast as well.

Comment: did you check your error log to see if there are other errors?

Comment: [Sun Jan 13 21:07:49 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: E:/Local Server/htdocs/content, referer: http://localhost:8080/test%20wp/

Comment: there are several logs like this one, after each of the upgrade attempts

Comment: i still say this is a server issue not a script issue

Comment: I agree with @keeg. It's probably not WP Core. WordPress takes awhile to update, period. Even on 100MB/s connections hosted in the cloud I've tested. Why don't you start by increasing/removing the limit on execution time and see how long it actually takes to finish ( if it finishes, which I think it will ).

Comment: This is clearly a download time problem - ini_set solved this for me - thanks!

Comment: RESTART APACHE. You can say that again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you cannot open connections from your server.
If you have access to the shell, can you ping a site, for example:

```
 ping google.com
```

If the ping fails you are most probably behind a fierwall that won't let you out.

Answer (score 0):

Open the `php.ini` file and replace

```
max_execution_time=valor
```

with

```
max_execution_time=0
```