# php foreach problems in Yii framework

Tags: php, memory, yii, foreach

I'm trying to integrate Multilingual behaviour into my Yii demo project "Trackstar". Model "project" is set for testing this multilingual behavior.

When I try to create an new project, I got an PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in (several different php scripts).

Debugging this eror, got strange foreach behavior in `/models/behaviors/MultilingualBehavior.php line 298:`

```
foreach ($this->languages as $l) { //$this->languages=array('en','lt');

var_dump($l) outputs very long list of 
s`tring(2) "en" string(2) "lt" string(2) "en" string(2) "lt" string(2) "en" string(2) "lt" string(2) "en" string(2) "lt" string(2) "en" string(2) "lt" string(2) "en" string(2) "lt" string(2) "en" string(2) "lt" string(2) "en" string(2) "lt"`
```

I'm using MAMP, php version 5.4.10

more info:

behaviors method in model/Project.php

```
public function behaviors() {
    return array(
        'ml' => array(
            'class' => 'application.models.behaviours.MultilingualBehavior',
            'langClassName' => 'Project',
            'langTableName' => 'tbl_projectLang',
            'langForeignKey' => 'project_id',
            'langField' => 'lang_id',
            'localizedAttributes' => array('name', 'description'), //attributes of the model to be translated
            'localizedPrefix' => 'l_',
            'languages' => array('en','lt'),
            'defaultLanguage' => 'en',
            'createScenario' => 'insert',
            //'localizedRelation' => 'i18nPost',
            'multilangRelation' => 'multilangProject',
            'forceOverwrite' => true,
            //'forceDelete' => true, 
            //'dynamicLangClass' => true, //Set to true if you don't want to create a 'PostLang.php' in your models folder
        ),
    );
}
```

/models/behaviours/MultilingualBehavior.php
method attach:

```
public function attach($owner) {
        parent::attach($owner);
        $owner_classname = get_class($owner);
        $table_name_chunks = explode('.', $owner->tableName());
        $simple_table_name = str_replace(array('{{', '}}'), '', array_pop($table_name_chunks));

        if (!isset($this->langClassName)) {
            $this->langClassName = $owner_classname . 'Lang';
        }
        if (!isset($this->langTableName)) {
            $this->langTableName = $simple_table_name . 'Lang';
        }
        if (!isset($this->localizedRelation)) {
            $this->localizedRelation = 'i18n' . $owner_classname;
        }
        if (!isset($this->multilangRelation)) {
            $this->multilangRelation = 'multilang' . $owner_classname;
        }
        if (!isset($this->langForeignKey)) {
            $this->langForeignKey = $simple_table_name . '_id';
        }
        if ($this->dynamicLangClass) {
            $this->createLangClass();
        }
        if (array_values($this->languages) !== $this->languages) { //associative array
            $this->languages = array_keys($this->languages);
        }
        $class = CActiveRecord::HAS_MANY;
        $this->createLocalizedRelation($owner, Yii::app()->language);
        $owner->getMetaData()->relations[$this->multilangRelation] = new $class($this->multilangRelation, $this->langClassName, $this->langForeignKey, array('index' => $this->langField));
        $rules = $owner->rules();
        $validators = $owner->getValidatorList();
        foreach ($this->languages as $l) {
            foreach($this->localizedAttributes as &$attr) {
                foreach($rules as $rule) {
                    $rule_attributes = array_map('trim', explode(',', $rule[0]));
                    if(in_array($attr, $rule_attributes)) {
                        if ($rule[1] !== 'required' || $this->forceOverwrite) {
                            $validators->add(CValidator::createValidator($rule[1], $owner, $attr . '_' . $l, array_slice($rule, 2)));
                        }
                        else if($rule[1] === 'required') {
                            //We add a safe rule in case the attribute has only a 'required' validation rule assigned
                            //and forceOverWrite == false
                            $validators->add(CValidator::createValidator('safe', $owner, $attr . '_' . $l, array_slice($rule, 2)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Solved it myself. My mistake was

> `'langClassName' => 'Project',` in /models/Project.php

that made recursive call of Project class instance + multilingualbehavior class witch call Project class an so on. Changed 'langClassName' => 'Project', to 'langClassName' => 'ProjectLang', got error The table "{{tbl_projectLang}}" for active record class "ProjectLang" cannot be found in the database. added 'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_', to /config/main.php db component and everything seems to be ok.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded

Comment: Please show some more code. The code provided does not match the results. It is certainly no memory problems (where did you get that idea from?) but as the error says, execution time exceeded. Your loop never ends.

Comment: I've doubt about 'langClassName' => 'Project', Changed to 'langClassName' => 'ProjectLang'. Got error "The table "{{tbl_projectLang}}" for active record class "ProjectLang" cannot be found in the database." I've created this table and behaviours method has 'langTableName' => 'tbl_projectLang',