# fatal error for max execution time

Tags: php

I have sequential function call which take few seconds of processing time. I faced this error:

[image]

Is there any way to remove this error?

I got this answer from previous threads:

You should check the max_execution_time setting in the php.ini files on your server and on your local installation.

Is there any other solution for this?

`MyURLDecode` is as below:

```
function MyURLDecode($url) 

{

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(

    CURLOPT_URL => $url,

    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,

    CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,

    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,));

    curl_exec($ch);

    $follow_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $follow_url;

}
```

Comment: I think curl code is timing out. Set `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` to 5 seconds and check curl error.

Comment: you can increase the max execution time of PHP in php.ini file. It's usually found in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` on your server then edit the line `max_execution_time = 30` and increase it to something higher.

Comment: @adamS: that is one solution as I mentioned in my question. IS there any other way to remove this error?

Comment: you could try these php functions http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time , http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Answer (score 3):

One way is to change the **max_execution_time** in php.ini or on runtime i.e.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', <total seconds>);
```

Another option is you can send your process in background.

Comment: here `1800` is what? millisecond?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 29);
```

Comment: What url you're use for test?
Try to use 
set_time_limit(0); 
above curl_init