# Upload csv file with 10000 record gets error "Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded" in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

When I upload CSV file in symfony2 with 10000 records it gets error "Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded".

Comment: Increase maximum execution time in `php.ini`

Comment: Or, speed up whatever you are doing. 10K records ought generally to load faster than 300 seconds.

Comment: use `set_time_limit(0);` in your controller class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: I used set_time_limit(0), still gets same error for timeout.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase maximum execution time on your php.ini as said before. 
You can also split your files into smaller, lighter files and process them separately.

Answer (score 0):

For bypass the the php.ini configuration you can set in your controller method the line:

```
public function verySlowerAction()
{
        set_time_limit(0);
....
}
```