# Maximum execution time for of 30 seconds exceeded in Goutte

Tags: php, web-crawler, ddos, goutte, flooding

Hi I am trying to crawl a website, specifically www.cvedetails.com and all the CVEs and after about 600 CVEs I got this error:

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in phar:///root/PHP/VULDRONE/goutte.phar/vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.php on line 173
```

I have changed the `max_execution_time` value in the `php.ini` to 900 seconds but apparently it doesn't work fine.

I am using also a sleep after X requests but no success, have tried to change the user-agent and the same.

I have no idea what can I do not for being blocked from the crawling.

Thank you in advance

Comment: try this function at the beginning of your php file  set_time_limit ( int $seconds ) ,it will definitely work  !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)