# Optimizing PHP Code and Storing JSON response to parse it faster?

Tags: php, curl, firewall, resolver

so I'm trying to figure out why does this PHP code takes too long to run to output the results.

for example this is my `apitest.php` and here is my PHP Code

```
<?php
function getRankedMatchHistory($summonerId,$serverName,$apiKey){
$k
$d;
$a;
$timeElapsed;
$gameType;
$championName;
$result;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://".$serverName.".api.pvp.net/api/lol/".$serverName."/v2.2/matchhistory/".$summonerId."?api_key=".$apiKey);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$matchHistory = json_decode($response,true); // Is the Whole JSON Response saved at $matchHistory Now locally as a variable or is it requested everytime $matchHistory is invoked ?
for ($i = 9; $i >= 0; $i--){
    $farm1 = $matchHistory["matches"][$i]["participants"]["0"]["stats"]["minionsKilled"];
    $farm2 = $matchHistory["matches"][$i]["participants"]["0"]["stats"]["neutralMinionsKilled"];
    $farm3 = $matchHistory["matches"][$i]["participants"]["0"]["stats"]["neutralminionsKilledTeamJungle"];
    $farm4 = $matchHistory["matches"][$i]["participants"]["0"]["stats"]["neutralminionsKilledEnemyJungle"];
    $elapsedTime = $matchHistory["matches"][$i]["matchDuration"];
    settype($elapsedTime, "integer");
    $elapsedTime = floor($elapsedTime / 60);
    $k = $matchHistory["matches"][$i]["participants"]["0"]["stats"]["kills"];
    $d = $matchHistory["matches"][$i]["participants"]["0"]["stats"]["deaths"];
    $a = $matchHistory["matches"][$i]["participants"]["0"]["stats"]["assists"];
    $championIdTmp = $matchHistory["matches"][$i]["participants"]["0"]["championId"];
    $championName =  call_user_func('getChampionName', $championIdTmp); // calls another function to resolve championId into championName
    $gameType = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $matchHistory["matches"][$i]["queueType"]);
    $result = (($matchHistory["matches"][$i]["participants"]["0"]["stats"]["winner"]) == "true") ? "Victory" : "Defeat";
    echo "<tr>"."<td>".$gameType."</td>"."<td>".$result."</td>"."<td>".$championName."</td>"."<td>".$k."/".$d."/".$a."</td>"."<td>".($farm1+$farm2+$farm3+$farm4)." in ". $elapsedTime. " minutes". "</td>"."</tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

What I'd like to know is how to make the page output faster as it takes around 
10~15 seconds to output the results which makes the browser thinks the website is dead like a 500 Internal error or something like it .

Here is a simple demonstration of how long it can take : [Here](http://ffat20.16mb.com/name.php?summonerName=alithespy&server=1)

As you might have noticed , yes I'm using Riot API which is sending the response as a JSON encoded type.

Here is an example of the response that this function handles : [Here](https://eune.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v2.2/matchhistory/29993137?api_key=33bc220a-4eab-4fb0-a403-e584ea7ad901)

What I thought of was creating a temporarily file called `temp.php` at the start of the CURL function and saving the whole response there and then reading the variables from there so i can speed up the process and after reading the variables it deletes the `temp.php` that was created thus freeing up disk space. and increasing the speed.

But I have no idea how to do that in PHP Only.

By the way I'd like to tell you that i just started using PHP today so I'd prefer some explanation with the answers if possible .

Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: The JSON response is stored locally in `$matchHistory` so there's no need to write it to a file.

Comment: Then Why does it takes ages to load the page , look at the demonstration link .

Comment: Try going to the API URL directly in your browser and see how long that takes. it's possible their server is just slow in giving you the response.

Comment: You will need to benchmark using `microtime(true)`

Comment: `local file on remote filesystem` sounds like contradiction...

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski What do you mean that it sounds like a contradiction ? will it reduce the page load speed ?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus added benchmark at the bottom of the demonstration page.

Comment: I am saying that if filesystem is remote then file stored on it cannot be local despite all the benchmarks :)

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood me. I'll post an answer below.

Comment: You can benchmark with `microtime`, or you can profile with [XDebug](http://xdebug.com) which will show you which parts of your code are taking the longest.

Comment: @AndyLester Already done that , check the Demonstration website please.

Comment: I still need help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try benchmarking like this:

```
// start the timer
$start_curl = microtime(true);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://".$serverName.".api.pvp.net/api/lol/".$serverName."/v2.2/matchhistory/".$summonerId."?api_key=".$apiKey);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// debugging
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 

// start another timer
$start = microtime(true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo 'curl_exec() in: '.(microtime(true) - $start).' seconds<br><br>';

// start another timer
$start = microtime(true);
curl_close($ch);
echo 'curl_close() in: '.(microtime(true) - $start).' seconds<br><br>';

// how long did the entire CURL take?
echo 'CURLed in: '.(microtime(true) - $start_curl).' seconds<br><br>';
```

Comment: CURLed in: 8.4606051445007 seconds.

check the demonstration website , I updated it. for only the getRankedMatchHistory function and since webpage loads for 11 seconds avg and this functions finish after 8.5 seconds , i guess it's the problem right.

Comment: @TheOnlyOne bingo! Now you know how to properly benchmark your app :-)

Comment: Yes but now I still don't know how to improve the load time.

Comment: @TheOnlyOne The URL which you are CURLing to is returning a 429 error. Have you looked into this? It is possible that the CURL is having issues with a 429 status code. I would look into debugging the CURL request with **[CURLOPT_VERBOSE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)**

Comment: Naah it just an API Rate limit exceeded error , here you go , you can use this link https://eune.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v2.2/matchhistory/29993137?api_key=13db9f40-3d10-4be6-81a8-6a9ed828136c

Comment: @TheOnlyOne I see, please see the updates in my answer.

Comment: @TheOnlyOne If PHP is not sufficient to solve the problem then you might need to install Wireshark on your server and debug the request at the network level. I would recommend creating a local web server on your machine and see if CURL behaves similarly. This could be a DNS related issue. Are you able to CURL to the service via IP address?

Comment: I have been getting a 500 Internal error because my php request took more than 20 second , another page using the same curl method to get a response from a different API .

So is there is a way to fix the 500 Internal error timeout ( fail safe time out i guess ) ?

Comment: @TheOnlyOne You can try the methods listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5164930/2191572) but if your server's security is tight then this might be off-limits for you. If you have 100% access to the server and it's OS then this should be feasible.