# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

**Fatal error:** Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in -

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\website.com\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1513

1513 line $theHeaders = WP_Http::processHeaders( $this->headers, $url );
```

Comment: Yes, and......? Do you expect us to be able to slow down time or something?

Comment: @MarcB Wonderful comment. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that `$this->headers` is holding tons of headers. that WP function loops over the headers in order to process them. Either increase the execution time in your ini or by `ini_set` (which I don't recommend), or check why `$this->headers` takes so long to process.

And, add more code, with that single line of code it will be impossible to SO users to detect the root cause of your problem.