# Maximum execution time in phpMyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, execution-time

When I try to go  phpMyadmin I get this error

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in 
             C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\session.inc.php on line 108
```

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded ?

Comment: @Mike Yes but not working

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Mike When i try to come in http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/ i get last message

Comment: Edit the php.ini in `\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini` and it might well make a difference to the PHP running under Apache

Comment: @Mike, not a particularly relevant Q&A

Comment: @RiggsFolly I Edit max_execution_time=300 not working

Comment: @Bobox Did you restart Apache afterwards?

Comment: Which `php.ini` file did you edit?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah, I agree. I voted to close it as well.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes I edit

Comment: your all trying to fix the symptom, not cure the disease. phpmyadmin should not be taking that long, something is wrong with the install

Comment: @Dagon Not necessarily, What is this guy actually doing in phpMyAdmin. The question is WAY TOO BROAD for anything other than guesses

Comment: **Which php.ini** did you edit, there are **2** One in the `\xampp\php\php.ini` which does not effect phpMyAdmin and one in `\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini` that does effect phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Dagon I've gone over 30 seconds on some phpmyadmin imports before. Of course, if the OP is just executing a regular query it's likely an indexing problem. As RiggsFolly said, it's way too broad to tell.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I edit \xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: So **read my other comments** make the `max_execution_time=300` change in `\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini` The `\xampp\php\php.ini` file only effects PHP CLI (Command Line Interface) i.e. running php from the command line

Comment: reads like he is visiting it to log in, not run a query - to me at least

Comment: @Dagon No see his last comment he is editing the wrong `php.ini` file

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think Dagon's point is that there is very little reason that the script should take more than 30 seconds in the first place.

Comment: @Mike unless like you said, he is actually doing an import of a large backup. That is the normal reason for this sort of issue

Comment: he just says hes visiting "localhost:8080/phpmyadmin " nothing about actually making a query

Comment: @RiggsFolly  how i  can  change   from command ?.

Comment: @Dagon I guess you have never watched `HOUSE`.

Comment: Huh? There was a House reference in here?

Comment: Bobox: Just to be sure, what are you doing once you get into the phpMyAdmin pages?

Comment: @Mike Patients lie, so do developers with issues. Or rather neglect to give all the facts

Comment: they call me Dr Dreamy at work.

Comment: @Dagon Lucky you, us ugle developers never get any of the breaks.... urm, thats not HOUSE by the way

Answer (score 1):

Bobox,

You are editing the wrong `php.ini` file. There are 2 `php.ini` files.

One is in `\xampp\php\php.ini`, this file only effects PHP that you run from the command line.

The other is in `\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini` this is the file that Apache uses when it runs, so this is the file you need to amend to effect the execution of `phpMyAdmin`.

So edit `\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini`

Find the `max_execution_time` parameter and change it to

```
max_execution_time=600
```

Then restart Apache, so that it reads this change then try running whatever you are doing in phpMyAdmin again.

If it still errors, try increasing the time parameter to 900, etc, until whatever it is works