# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded after changing php.ini

Tags: php, xampp

I use XAMPP and changed the php.ini in C:\xampp\php\php.ini:

from -> max_execution_time=30

to -> max_execution_time=3000

I still get the error: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

What can I do?

Comment: Have you restarted apache service?

Comment: Please refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it is not php.ini only. I had to add ini_set('max_execution_time', 120); to my php file too.

Answer (score 0):

try my response in :

[Execution time limit in php not setting to infinte time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68922650/execution-time-limit-in-php-not-setting-to-infinte-time/68922770#68922770)

0 value for infinite var :

```
max_execution_time=0
max_input_time=0
```