# Execution time limit in php not setting to infinte time?

Tags: php, python-2.7, xampp

I have given these settings on my php.ini which is a xampp v3.30 version

```
max_execution_time=10000
max_input_time=60
```

My php script calls an python api which loops db and get value back to php page in a 15 min time. Now the script change and and it takes more than 15 min. approx 1 hour to get back the data to page. so I changes the setting to

```
max_execution_time=21600
max_input_time=21600
default_socket_timeout=21600
```

But still the php page exit at an exact 20 min time, but I can see the python server still running and gives the result to server console after the said time. How can I set my web page to by pass this timeout ? Please help and thanks in advance. I searched a lot tried but it not giving me a result.

Comment: With web servers, you are always subject to the web server's timeout setting, the browser's timeout setting, and external settings. Instead, either find a way to speed up the process, or figure out how to offload it, and possibly send the results another way such as email.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a value set to 0 (and sometimes -1) describes infinity

Try this :

```
max_execution_time=0
max_input_time=0
```

source :

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time
https://www.php.net/manual/fr/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time