# Cron Jobs, long php scripts and time limit (this not related to server time limit but to cron job time limit)

Tags: php, database, cron

I have a database where I have to save a lot of data.
All this data recovered from an Unofficial API that retrieve data from official site.
Unofficial API is the only one I can use, because official API is really short developed, but Unofficial API is really really slow.
I couldn't do anything to speed up this process.

To automate data update, I've created php pages that recovers data from Unofficial API, combine it and store it into the database.
These pages refresh every 30 seconds continuing process in order to avoid server time limit, set to 30 secs and not modifiable.

Than I've created multiple cron jobs.
But there's a problem.
Cron jobs work for at least 30/60/90/120 seconds, but the whole data update process can goes on for 20/30 mins.

Do you have any good idea on how to solve this problem?

***I'll be more clear, sorry.***

The problem is this:
- script is long about 20/30 mins, divided in multiple auto-loads, this recover and load all the data into the database;
- a cron job works for max 120 seconds than it returns a time-out error.

I need, if possibile, to find a way to have all data loaded into database, four time a day.

Do you have any idea?

***Second update.***

This is not a question related to TIME LIMIT of SERVER, I've overcome this problem cutting my script in pieces.
This is a metter of CRON JOB TIME LIMIT.
I cannot do anything (that I know) to accelerate script execution, so my data recover is really long and I need time execute it all, but cron jobs are too fast.

Comment: What problem? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Thx for answer. I've edited post, pls check update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: No billynoah is not a metter of server maximum execution time.
I've solved this problem with a process that stops at 29 seconds, than post same page and continue process (I cannot set max execution time on server to infinte).

The problem is with cron jobs max execution time that is set to 30/60/90/120 sec depending on service you choose... and this is also not modifiable...

Comment: I've checked and it seems there aren't hosts that give you cron jobs longer than 1200 seconds.