# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, execution-time

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4758
```

I have this error, and the line 4758, that are the function "wp_debug_backtrace_summary". And there another error in:

> htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php

at the line 520-525-575 what is the wordpress function `do_action($tag, $arg = '')` .

I triyed this: `/while ( is_array($wp_filter[$tag]) && next($wp_filter[$tag]) !== false );` reset the server, and clean the plugins.

What could be the cause?

PS: i searched arround the internet but i don't understand many about wordpress.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: i tried this too, and didn't worked, sorry i forget mention this

Comment: wordpress codex will tell you all about the wordpress functions..

Comment: Disable your plugins one by one to find out the culprit. And never touch wordpress core files. If all plugins are disabled and you still get this error, switch to the default theme.

Comment: Try adding `@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', 600 );` to your wp-config.php

Comment: i triyed it and has not worked, sorry

Comment: i tried too with 1200 and  1500