# Next() array error

Tags: php

I have array: `$stack` and function that walks this stack:

```
private function nextStep()
    {
        echo "Next\r\n";
        return next($this->stack);
    }
```

I call this functions in infinity loop, but I sure that this array is full until condition then I dont call `nextStep` anymore.

So, I get error in `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in private function nextStep()`

Whats does it mean and how to fix?

I call this as:

```
private function parseHTML()
{

   if ($this->nextStep() == false) {

   sleep($this->timeout);
   $this->parse();

   } else {

   $this->parseNextStack();
   }

}

private function currentStack()
{
   $this->currentStackItem = current($this->stack);

}

private function nextStep()
{
   try {
     return next($this->stack);
   }

   catch (Exception $e){

    echo count($this->stack); die();
   }

}

private function parseNextStack(){

   sleep($this->timeout);
   $this->nextStep();
   $this->currentStack();
   $this->parseHTML(); // HERE IS LOOP
}
```

So, init function is: `parseHTML()` from that script is started

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: could you please provide the loop in question? and how large is `$this->stack`?

Comment: One moment will share this

Comment: How can I catch this array and get size immediately?

Comment: please show the code where you are calling this method.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of function [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: I tried, but this is not way out. I tried:` ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`. I must to get reason of this behavior

Comment: Also I can not catch this when error is appeared: ` echo count($this->stack);`

Comment: Script is falled when size of stack is `49` elements

Comment: It happens even if stack is small size, for example 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that loop has correct condition to end it then probably array $stack is too big. You can increase maximum execution time in file php.ini - parameter max_execution_time.