# Laravel Dompdf - Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, dompdf

In My Laravel Application, I using DOMPDF to generate pdf files. When i convert Portrait Invoices its working properly. When i convert Landscape Invoices Its Display following Error **Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in Frame.php (line 0)**

My Controller Code is :

```
return \PDF::loadView('pdf/invoice', compact('salesinvoiceData','companyData','salesitemsData'))->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')->setWarnings(false)->download($salesinvoiceData->id.'.pdf');
```

Comment: Looks like you have large file to convert to pdf

Answer (score 2):

I think includes css & js is the cause of slow load when generating pdf.

This is my code before:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
test
@endsection
```

After remove @extends problem is fixed

```
test
```

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the max execution time:

```
set_time_limit(300); // Extends to 5 minutes.

// Then return the PDF
return \PDF::loadView(/* ... */)->download($salesinvoiceData->id.'.pdf');;
```

See: [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded) for more information.

Comment: @Karthik did it fix your problem?

Comment: 60 seconds are enough