# Issue with max_execution_time limit, despite trying every directive I could find

Tags: php, time, max, execution, mamp-pro

I'm trying to upload a demo content for a template I'm using but it gets stuck and never uploads.

Using Mamp Pro on localhost configuration. Here is the log that I get everytime I try to run the upload:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1877
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php:0
PHP   2. do_action() C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-admin\admin-ajax.php:91
PHP   3. WP_Hook->do_action() C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-includes\plugin.php:453
PHP   4. WP_Hook->apply_filters() C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:323
    PHP   5. stm_demo_import_content() C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:298
PHP   6. WP_Import->import() C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-content\plugins\stm-importer\stm-importer.php:241
PHP   7. WP_Import->process_posts() C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-content\plugins\stm-importer\wordpress-importer\wordpress-importer.php:106
PHP   8. add_post_meta() C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-content\plugins\stm-importer\wordpress-importer\wordpress-importer.php:731
PHP   9. add_metadata() C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-includes\post.php:1716
PHP  10. wpdb->insert() C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-includes\meta.php:99
PHP  11. wpdb->_insert_replace_helper() C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1910
PHP  12. wpdb->query() C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1989   
PHP 13. wpdb->_do_query() C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1765
```

`php.ini` is reconfigured with `max_execution_time = 600` and `max_input_time = 600`

I've added directive `TimeOut 600` in `httpd.conf` (at the end of virtualhost block)

httpd.conf-default timeout directives are both set on 600

`wp_config` is set with `set_time_limit(600);`

and `.htaccess` Mamp-pro is configured so that it overrides it

Despite all of these, I still get the 60 seconds max execution time exceeded. I've browsed this site and many others without luck. I'm no coder so I can't see in the files in the stack trace if there is anything that should be amended.

Comment: What is the actual query that you are trying to run that takes that much time?

Comment: Show us how you've set the max timeout in your htaccess.

Comment: I'm trying to upload demo content for a template. The template recommends 300 seconds as it takes a few minutes. I've set it to 600 in a desperate attempt to make it work I confess.

Comment: I've not set anything in .htaccess since Mamp Pro is configured to override it

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: Set up a phpinfo(); function in a test.php file.  Visit it to verify that your setting is taking effect.

Comment: yes everytime I made a change somewhere

Comment: php.info shows all the right config for all directives

Comment: What do you mean by _"Mamp Pro is configured to override it"_ when referring to htaccess? How is it configured to do so? Is "AllowOverride" set to "None"?

Comment: Try this out : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25706550/8461611

Comment: Re .htaccess overriden by mamp pro http://blog-en.mamp.info/2015/02/the-htaccess-file-and-mamp-pro.html

Comment: That's not Mamp overriding htaccess. That's how you either enable or disable htaccess files. If you set "AllowOverride" to "All", then you can use htaccess to override Apache settings. Just set it to "All" and then try adding the time limit to the htacccess: `php_value max_execution_time 600`

Comment: nope, problem with execution time still here sorry

Comment: although I have a 2nd notice and stack trace on the log file despite the 60 seconds exceeded: 'Notice:  wp_get_http is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.4.0! Use WP_Http instead. in C:\MAMP\htdocs\\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3831
[10-Sep-2017 00:13:27 UTC] PHP Stack trace:

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.