# php cURL post exceed execution time issue

Tags: php, curl

I've asked about this before but didn't explain myself quite well.

Point is I've been working with cURL post requests and had no problem till now.

I'm trying to send a post request from my remote server:

```
$file = json_encode($mysqli_select_query);
$file = openssl_encrypt($file, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0, $iv);
$file = base64_encode($file);
```

**$file** is a select query from database encrypted with openssl_encrypt and then encoded into base64

```
$array = array(
    'file' => $file,
    'action' => 1,
);

$array = http_build_query($array);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://domain_name.com/absolute/path/to/script.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

but only thing I receive is

```
PHP Fatal error : Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

**NOTE:**

On previous cases what I did was sent a request to local server and retrieving information [*mysqli select query*] to put into my remote server and it worked well with no errors or warnings.

But know that I'm trying to send information from remote server to local and It's giving me the problems I mentioned before.

**Does anyone know how to solve this?**

***UPDATE:***

The **Maximum execution time exceeded** error line is the same as

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Does this mean that the problem could be on the external script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: TL;DR your file is taking longer than 30 seconds to upload, so PHP is killing your script, increase the execution time for your script

Comment: How can I do that? @zack6849

Comment: edit php.ini and increase max_execution_time to something higher

Comment: @zack6849 thanks! I'll try it later.

Comment: @zack6849 didn't work. I'm gonna try to send the data as a file.txt and retrieve it on the local server cause I think the main problem is the length of the string pass as post variable...

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether you **local** or your **remote** server displays the message and then increase the [max_execution_time](http://php.net/max-execution-time) on that system to some higher value than 30 seconds. I don't think that this is related to cURL in any way

Comment: It's remote server. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have control over the script and the environment triggered on the remote server?

Comment: Yes I do. My question is if I can increase the max_execution_time value on the script or I need to change php.ini

Comment: I have updated my question. And thanks for trying to help me!