# how to update value of xml using PHP

Tags: php, xml

i have this .xml file..

```
<product>
    <id>4021</id>
    <product_code>1220211</product_code>
    <barcode>1220211</barcode>
    <title>sera Pond granulat - храна на гранули</title>
    <price>71.65</price>
    <meta_title>sera Pond granulat - храна на гранули</meta_title>
    <meta_description>sera Pond granulat, 21 000 мл</meta_description>
</product>
```

With this php code i want to create meta decsription of all products.

```
<?php
  $xml=simplexml_load_file("zoo.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
       foreach($xml->children() as $desc) { 
         echo $desc->title . "  "; 
         echo $desc->price . " лв. "; 
       echo ' some text here' . "<br>";
   } 
?>
```

How to update all meta_description in the same file with created text. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to create description of my product base on title and price from product, title+price=description

Comment: Missing implementation is not really a good programming question. So what approaches have you tried so far to tackle this one? Care to provide a code example where you demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I don't know hot to update field meta_description in the xml file after create the text with php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to change the text of the last element, you can access it the same way as you fetch the value for your `echo` statements...

```
foreach($xml->product as $desc) {
    echo $desc->title . "  ";
    echo $desc->price . " лв. ";
    $desc->meta_description = $desc->title . "  ".$desc->price . " лв. ";
}
```

Don't forget to save the data afterwards back to the file

```
$xml->asXML("zoo.xml");
```

Comment: Working perfect! Only this error
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/itbuddiesbg/public_html/import/xml.php on line 12

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded may help with sorting that out.