# PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\symfony\process\Pipes\WindowsPipes.php on line 140

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, symfony, ffmpeg-php

When I try to upload video that is larger than 15MB using Ajax and Laravel I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\symfony\process\Pipes\WindowsPipes.php on line 140

I use `Ffmpeg` and `Symfony/process`

the error in `symfony windowsPipes.php` in Laravel.

What is problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: 60 seconds sounds like it should be enough to upload a 15mb file. What other things are you doing with it?

Comment: i use ffmpeg to encoding video to add watermark

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set max_execution_time in your php.ini:

```
max_execution_time=300
```

Or, in your PHP code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); // 5 minutes
```

Setting it to zero removes the restriction, however apache might also time out in that scenario.

Check the manual
http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

> This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly written scripts from tying up the server. The default setting is 30. When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.
>
> The maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream operations etc. Please see the set_time_limit() function for more details.
>
> You can not change this setting with ini_set() when running in safe mode. The only workaround is to turn off safe mode or by changing the time limit in the php.ini.
>
> Your web server can have other timeout configurations that may also interrupt PHP execution. Apache has a Timeout directive and IIS has a CGI timeout function. Both default to 300 seconds. See your web server documentation for specific details.

Comment: when i added it in my php.ini,  its show me this error 
`PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in C:\xampp\php\php.ini on line 221`

Comment: @GhyathDarwish because this is PHP code, not config. If you want to write it in php.ini, you have to write just `max_execution_time=300`

Comment: i also restarted server, but it is still

Comment: `set_time_limit(300)` in your PHP code might work as well

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that uploading is taking more then 30 sec,  you could extend the maximum execution time like this, go to php.ini in your xampp and set this

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting *max_execution_time* in php.ini file may not work in all scenarios, anyway set it for some *300* seconds. But for all scenarios, writing `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` in the file you want to execute will do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1.

`set_time_limit` set the maximum execution time for the current script without altering the php.ini file. The change is temporary and applies only to the current script.

```
set_time_limit(300); // 5 minutes
```

2. 

`init_set` modifies the `max_execution_time` directive in the php.ini file, affecting all PHP pages using this configuration. As described in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) "The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending".

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); // 5 minutes
```

Both functions limit the execution time of a PHP script, but `set_time_limit` affects only the current script, while `ini_set` influences all PHP pages using the configuration directive.

Comment: False; calling `ini_set()` does not persist the changes, and only works in the context of the current request, just like `set_time_limit()`. I believe the main difference between the two is that calling `set_time_limit()` actually restarts the timer, while `ini_set()` supposedly doesn't.

Comment: tnks, its work for me

Comment: @Duroth it's explained in `ini_set` documentation: "The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending".