# XAMPP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: mysql, xampp

I get:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Session.php on line 189

In my `php.ini` I have already set the maximum execution time to maximum.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Answer (score 0):

What error? (missing information in question)

First check what limit You really have:

```
 echo ini_get('max_execution_time');
```

Limit can be set in php.ini or .htaccess or in PHP code (set_time_limit(30)) - check all places.

Limit in .htaccess can block PHP code setting.

Comment: sorry my bad i mean Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Session.php on line 189

Comment: so my guess was right ;)  Did my answer help you solve problem? If not write  more information what you see in places I mention above

Comment: please provide a more detailed explanation or tutorial because I'm still a beginner

Comment: Start with test:   echo ini_get('max_execution_time');  set_time_limit(90); echo ini_get('max_execution_time'); , then if this not working, check .htaccess file for line like : php_value max_execution_time 30.. Check phpinfo() - what value you have there, and php.ini path  (maybe you edited wrong php.ini file)

Answer (score 0):

Clearing browser cache, local storage for site **http://localhost/phpmyadmin/** was enough to resolve this issue for me. As I tested it first in incognito mode there was no issue in incognito mode.