# How to increase maximum execution time in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I want to upload large excel file. But because the file contains many rows, the loading is so slow and I got this error:

> FatalErrorException in Controller.php line 457: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded

I already put this on my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value max_execution_time 1500
    php_value upload_max_filesize 15M
</IfModule>
```

I also add this at the top of the controller:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '3000M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
```

I also change max_execution_time at the php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 300
```

And also add this on config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

I wonder why it's not work at all and keep getting me into that error... Is there a miss at the code? Any help would be appreciate, Thanks!

Comment: Check the php.ini from your apache/bin folder

Comment: It would be lovely if you did some research before posting a question that has _multiple_ duplicates already on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded

Answer (score 14):

To temporarily set the limit, You can just do this in the code

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

or

```
set_time_limit(300);
```

To change permanently, change the following values in `php.ini`

```
max_execution_time = 360      ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds (I CHANGED THIS VALUE)
max_input_time = 120          ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 128M           ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB by default)
```

Comment: in what part of the code?

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz mileage might vary based on the Laravel major but putting that in the boot method of your service provider should work.

Answer (score 5):

Edit **php.ini**:

**php.ini** path : `/etc/[your php version example:php5]/apache2/php.ini`

```
max_execution_time = 360      ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds (I CHANGED THIS VALUE)
max_input_time = 120          ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 128M           ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB by default)
```

I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this in your controller before the query

`set_time_limit(300);`