# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\AKS_Shop\wp-includes\Requests\Transport\cURL.php on line 463

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to install the **plugin** but this error:-

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\AKS_Shop\wp-includes\Requests\Transport\cURL.php on line 463

taking place if anybody knows the solution about it then plz guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Some curl request fails, because it takes longer than 30 seconds to execute. You can raise that time in your php config. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded).

But you should also debug, why the command is taking that much time. Is the plugin trustworthy and up to date?