# Error 504 Timeout only when saving courses/activities in Moodle

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, moodle

We recently experienced a 504 Timeout error on a Moodle site when saving or updating courses from the administrator. After 60 seconds the 504 Timeout error appears and does not let the administrator user do anything until after 5-6 minutes and the strange thing is that he did save and modify what the administrator did.

This error only happens with the user who is editing the course and sends it to save. No other user (other than an administrator) exhibits the 504 Timeout problem.

Windows Server is being used with IIS, PHP 7.4, Moodle 3.8.x and Windows SQL Server (as DB)

Do you know what the problem would be? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: @Top-Master No, I already tried that solution and the 504 Timeout continues to the user, but the information is saved in DB

Comment: Could be a post save event for specific users. Is there any custom code on the site? If there is, then check the content of pluginname/db/events.php, then check the code its calling. Otherwise you'll probably need to use step by step debugging.