# Using PHP to read real time serial data

Tags: php, xml, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I am using a Raspberry Pi to read real time RS232 data via a USB port using a Prolific 2303 adaptor.

I want to parse this and display it in a web page.
My first approach was to use a python script. This could read and parse the data but passing it to a PHP web page proved a problem. Either I could use GET to send it or save it to a file and read it with PHP. The latter is a non starter with an SD card, it's not going to last too long and the former might involve file storage anyway.

I then tried a PHP approach;

```
$device = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
$fp = fopen($device,"r") or die();
while(true){
  $xml = fread($fp,"400");
    print_r($xml);
}
fclose($fp);
```

`print_r();` produces:

```
CC128-v0.110011909:27:3016.70000951000660008500024 CC128-v0.110011909:27:3616.70000951000670008600024 CC128-v0.110011909:27:4216.70000951000680008700027 CC128-v0.110011909:27:4816.70000951000680008600024 CC128-v0.110011909:27:5516.70000951000680008800024
```

This is 5 bursts of XML stripped of all its tags. The complete XML stream is 340 characters long, 57600-N-8-1 sent every 6 seconds.

Then it crashes with "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in ~/meter.php on line 79" Sometimes there is missing or corrupted data, too.

If I use `$xml = fgets($fp);` I get no data.

The stream I am expecting, as read using a Python is:

```
['<msg><src>CC128-v0.11</src><dsb>00114</dsb><time>17:45:02</time><tmpr>16.8</tmpr><sensor>0</sensor><id>00095</id><type>1</type><ch1><watts>00065</watts></ch1><ch2><watts>00093</watts></ch2><ch3><watts>00024</watts></ch3></msg>\r\n']
```

I tried to use PECL-DIO but could not locate all the dependencies. Apparently, it is deprecated for the current version of Debian and will be removed from the next. I don't know if that refers to Buster, Bullseye or Bookworm. I also tried using php_serial.class which I found on GIT but could not get a complete XML file output or even the stripped down data only stream.

What am I missing to get a PHP variable updated every 6 seconds?

Comment: Use AJAX to send requests to a php file every X seconds. The php file reads/returns the data, use Javascript to display it on your webpage

Comment: You can [increase PHP’s time limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5164954/231316). However, how much data do you care about. Is it only “now”, or do you want historical?

Comment: I guess you have spotted that this is a Current Cost Monitor. The historic data will go to the database, once I can read it. If I could detect the end of the data message I can exit the 'while loop' and restart it for the next message so the timeout would not be a problem. It seems that the 'fread()' is running much slower than the data but that still does not explain why it doesn't stop after the 400 bytes or is the limitation 'fopen()'?

Comment: `fread` returns false once it reaches the end of the stream, have you tried checking for that?