# Efficient bulk data insertion (250k records) in Laravel without exceeding PHP time limit? (Queue, multi-tenancy)

Tags: php, laravel, database, performance, eloquent

I'm encountering a PHP execution time error while inserting approximately 250k records into a MySQL database using Laravel Eloquent. I'm aiming to achieve this without increasing the overall execution time, considering the following constraints:

1. **Frontend**: Angular
2. **Multi-tenancy**: Implemented using
   [https://tenancyforlaravel.com/](https://tenancyforlaravel.com)
3. **Attempted solutions**: Laravel Queue

Below is my code.

Job File Code -

```
class MedicineData implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels, Batchable;

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;

    }

    public function handle(): void
    {
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
            $medicine = new MedicineName();
            $medicine->name = $value['name'];
            $medicine->save();
        }
    }

}
```

Controller File Code

```
$chunks = array_chunk($data, 500);
$batch = Bus::batch([])->dispatch();

foreach ($chunks as $key => $value) {
    $batch->add(new MedicineData($value));
}
```

I am getting an error of Maximum PHP Execution Time. How to resolve this.

Comment: It would be interesting to see more details about your "attempted solution", as your problem sounds like a perfect fit for a message queue.

Comment: `2.5 lakh` is it 250,000 ?

Comment: @HonkderHase Yes, 2.5 lakhs = 250000

Comment: @Repox You need code snippets?

Comment: Well, [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is not a site for debating ideas or seeking recommendations. Clarify your problem, what you've tried and what you expected and what you got instead.

Comment: Please don't use local words like `lakh` here. As you've noticed, not everyone will understand them.

Comment: @Repox I added the code please review it and give me your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve the problem using the below code. But it is taking more than 20 minutes to insert 250K data into my database.

```
set_time_limit(WRITE_YOUR_PREFERRED_TIME_HERE_IN_SECONDS);
```

I got the solution from another Stack Overflow Post. That post link is -
[Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: User asked for No PHP Time Increase Solution.

Answer (score -2):

In your case, using Laravel queues is a step in the right direction, but you may need to tweak your approach to make it more efficient. You need to some optimizations in your queue logic:

```
public function handle(): void
{
    $dataToInsert = [];
    foreach ($this->data as $value) {
        $dataToInsert[] = [
            'name' => $value['name'],
            // other attributes...
        ];
    }
    // use insert method to bulk inserting
    MedicineName::insert($dataToInsert);

    // If your $this->data already formated array than no need to run loop for formating
    // use direct insert on Model
    // MedicineName::insert($this->data);
}
```

The insert method is more suitable for bulk inserts and allows you to insert multiple records into the database with a single query.

Comment: **Reminder:** Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. [Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy)